# Extra Square brackets Get added when retrieve Json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ionic-framework

I am Trying to retrieve data from json in my code. Json data doesn't contain any brackets. It is just any array separated by commas(,). My **Problem** is that when I get data using *$scope*, an extra sqaure bracket get added outside my output. Demo of my code is
**controller.js**

```
$http.get("serverUrl")
    .success(function(data) { 
        $scope.sour = data;
})
    .error(function(err) {
        console.log("Error in source: "+JSON.stringify(err));
    });
```

**html**

```
<div>
  {{sour}}
</div
```

**expected json**

```
data
```

**error**

```
[data]
```

I have **tried** old stack solutions but none of them worked out for me.
Please share if anyone know why this error being produced, As I have used this method a hundred times before but never faced this problem.
Regards.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please mention the exact error.

Comment: thanks for responding . I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

After trying found out a solution.

`.toString().replace();`

solved out my problem.

Comment: *But* Still don't  know the actual reason behind thus error.  If anyone knows, then kindly post it here.

Comment: well I tried but It says that I can mark it after 2 days. Sort of blocked I think.

Comment: Oh, I said nothing then :)

Answer (score 0):

As per how `JSON.stringify` should work as specified [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3), the result that you explained is as expected.

> 1. Let separator be the result of concatenating the comma character,
>      the line feed character, and indent.
> 2. Let properties be a String
>      formed by concatenating all the element Strings of partial with each
>      adjacent pair of Strings separated with separator. The separator
>      String is not inserted either before the first String or after the
>      last String.
> 3. Let final be the result of concatenating "[", the line
>      feed character, indent, properties, the line feed character,
>      stepback, and "]"

Which will result in a **valid** `JSON` String. The format you are requesting is confusing and is probably an invalid JSON. You can try checking the `JSON` using some [`JSON` validator online](http://jsonlint.com). (Notice that `[1,2,3,4]` is **valid** where as `1,2,3,4` is **invalid**)

You are probably having a service that is expecting a malformed `JSON`, it will be better to fix that part instead of duck taping your `JSON`.

*Meanwhile, the only thing you are explaining is the format you are getting and the format that is working. You haven't still specified where exactly the error happens? Is it error from HTTP request? Is it error thrown in Javascript? What is causing the error? What error messages are you getting?*

Comment: My json is like [1,2,3,4] but we retrieve json {{data}} in view then the square brackets aren't expected to show in view if they are added in json format whereas they show only if we have added them manually in the json.

Comment: Can you explain this further? What you are trying to explain is not clear.